# command line argument to run a c program

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){

    // read in the command-line argument
    double x,c;
    double epsilon = 1e-15;    // relative error tolerance
    double t ; // estimate of the square root of c
    //scanf("%lf",&t);
    t=**argv-'0';
    printf("%lf ",t);
    c=t;
    // repeatedly apply Newton update step until desired precision is achieved
    while (fabs(t - c/t) > epsilon*t) {
        t = (c/t + t) / 2.0;
    }
    // print out the estimate of the square root of c
    printf("%lf",t);

    return 0;
}
```

In this program i want to run with command line argument . how can i do that?

Comment: What does `x` do in your program?

Comment: Thanks all of you to answer me. I got my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open up a terminal(command-line) and type "gcc nameOfFile.c argument1 argument2" 
don't type the quotes though. Each argument you type will get passed in to your program and can be accessed by argv[0], argv[1], etc

Comment: i do this with nameOfFile.exe 0 2 but it doesn't work.It always gives result 67.000000 8.185353.

Answer (score 4):

To run the command line argument from terminal you need to use this syntax

```
gcc filename.c

./a.out "your argument her without quotation mark"
```

Answer (score 2):

The number of command-line arguments is in `argc`.  Each argument is in `argv[0]`, `argv[1]`, etc.  Conventionally, `argv[0]` contains the name of the executable.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `scanf` (which operates on standard input), use `sscanf`, which operates on a string.
So that would be

```
sscanf(argv[1], "%lf", &t);
```

to scan the first command line argument.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you want to pass a double value to your program. But you are using `**argv` to retrieve the double passed from the command-line. But `**argv` is really a single char.

What you need to do is convert the string into double using `atof()`.

```
t = atof(argv[1]); // argv[1] is the 1st parameter passed.
```

Another potential issue is, here: `fabs(t - c/t)` If `t` ever becomes 0, you may face *divide-by-zero*.

Answer (score 1):

1) you need to use argc (the #/command line parameters) and argv[] (the parameters themselves).

2) It's always a good idea to check argc before accessing a command line variable (i.e. to make sure you actually *got* the command-line parameter, before you try to use it).

3) There are several ways to convert the command-line parameter (a string) to a real.  In general, I prefer "sscanf()".

Here's an example:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){

    double x,c;
    double epsilon = 1e-15;    // relative error tolerance
    double t ; // estimate of the square root of c

    //scanf("%lf",&t);
    if (argc != 2) {
      printf ("USAGE: enter \"t\"\n")l
      return 1;
    } 
    else  if (sscanf (argv[1], "%lf", &t) != 1) {
      printf ("Illegal value for \"t\": %s\n", argv[1]);
      return 1;
    }

    printf("%lf ",t);
    c=t;
    // repeatedly apply Newton update step until desired precision is achieved
    while (fabs(t - c/t) > epsilon*t) {
        t = (c/t + t) / 2.0;
    }
    // print out the estimate of the square root of c
    printf("%lf",t);

    return 0;
}
```